# Иконка на папке с данными приложения

Tags: android

Создал папку для хранения данных

```
String pathData = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
        "/android/data/ru.frozik6k/lohouse/";
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            File path = new File(pathData);
            if (!path.exists())  path.mkdirs(); 
}
```

Папка нормально создается, данные сохраняются в ней. Но вот заметил, на других приложениях иконка приложения нарисована. А на моей папке с данными нет, и если мою программу удалить, то папка остается. Как тогда правильно создавать эту папку, чтобы иконка была, и папка удалялась при удалении самой программы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы получить путь к директории с данными вашего приложения на Sd-карте, надо использовать `Context.getExternalFilesDir(null)`.
Это вернет путь вида  `sdcard/Android/data/data/<тут package вашего приложения>/`